# how to count the particular string in row wise in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

```
name | sub1 | sub2 | sub3
__________________________
prad |  poor| good | poor
vas  | good | poor | poor
```

I want to count the number of 'poor' each person getting

I tried the query  `"SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM tbl_name where (sub1,sub2,sub3)='poor' group by name;"`
It doesn't work ..please help 
How can I count row wise?

Comment: It is not clear what the table structure. Is it `name|sub1|sub2|sub`? If so, it has just 4 columns and the data you provided `prad|poor|etc` exceeds it. Can you give a better example providing table structure and table data in a friendlier way? Thanks.

Comment: actually the 2nd row start from the word "vas"

Comment: i can calculate that the sub3 has two "poor" . but how can i calculate the no of "poor" does vas or prad have

Comment: That was not your original question. Mark this as answered and then ask another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you can have many equal names in your table (you didn't specify what was the primary key):

```
select name, sum(
    if (sub1='poor', 1, 0) +
    if (sub2='poor', 1, 0) +
    if (sub3='poor', 1, 0)
) as total from Data
group by name;
```

Here is an [example](http://www.sqlize.com/1aOxX7fH8b)

Or this if you don't have repeated names in your table:

```
select name,
    if (sub1='poor', 1, 0) +
    if (sub2='poor', 1, 0) +
    if (sub3='poor', 1, 0)
as total from Data
```

Here is an [example](http://www.sqlize.com/5LEc1CdAIl)

Let me know if this works.

Comment: thank you ..it works then i wil do this with roll no as primary key

Comment: Great. If it works, then you should mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT name, (IF(sub1='poor',1,0) + IF(sub2='poor',1,0)+
>   IF(sub3='poor',1,0))  AS Total_Poor FROM demo1 GROUP BY name;

Answer (score -1):

If you're limiting it to just `poor`, the GROUP is pointless:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM tbl_name WHERE name='poor'
```

Comment: i can calculate that the sub3 has two "poor" . but how can i calculate the no of "poor" does vas or prad have